# How to not trigger router middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Express states [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use) that:

> A route will match any path that follows its path immediately with a
>   “/”. For example: app.use('/apple', ...) will match “/apple”,
>   “/apple/images”, “/apple/images/news”, and so on.

so, suppose I have two router middleware functions:

```
app.get('/apple', function() {});
app.get('/apple/images', function() {});
```

and the request is

```
GET http://domain.com/apple/images
```

so I want that my second function to process the request, but as I understand the first one will be called as well, correct? Is there any way to skip the first one? I understand that I can call `next()` from the first function:

```
app.get('/apple', function(req,res,next) {next()});
```

but is it really how it should be done? Should I use `next('router')` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order matters. Define the longer path first and you'll get the behavior you want.